# Jquery - How to change part of attribute href in link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know what I am doing wrong with changing href attribute in link from ?page to &page. It stays on ?page. Thank you for any advice.

Jquery:

```
var article_pagination_change = function(){
    $('pagination a').each(function(){
       $(this).href.replace('?page','&page');
    });
}
article_pagination_change();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="pagination80" class="pagination" style="">
  <a class="first" data-action="first" href="?page=1">&lt;&lt;</a>
  <a class="previous" data-action="previous" href="?page=1">&lt;</a>
  <input class="pag_input_80" type="text" value="1 of 12" data-max-page="12" readonly="readonly">
  <a class="next" data-action="next" href="?page=2">&gt;</a>
  <a class="last" data-action="last" href="?page=12">&gt;&gt;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: that dot is very small I can't see it :) thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually set the attribute:

```
var article_pagination_change = function(){
    $('.pagination a').each(function(){
        var newurl = $(this).attr('href').replace('?page','&page');
        $(this).attr('href', newurl);
    });
}
article_pagination_change();
```

Note that I added the `.` before `pagination` and am using `attr('href')` instead of just `href`.

[**Here's a working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/uQd9h/1/).

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind changing your code a bit more, you can try this simpler approach:

```
var article_pagination_change = function(){
    $('.pagination a').attr('href',function(index,attr){
       return attr.replace('?','&');
    });
}
article_pagination_change();
```

You don't really need the `.each()` nor replacing `?page` with `&page` unless you had extra `?`s on your `href`s...

**[Sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/xyfH4/1/)**

Comment: @EdCottrell it was a sudden idea, anyways your answer is good as well sir, so +1 back...